# 3-node Docker Swarm through VPN

Tags: docker, networking, vpn, swarm

I've got a 3 node docker swarm running through a VPN. I'm having trouble getting containers going on my worker nodes (they can join the swarm successfully) this is the error I keep running into

```
"network sandbox join failed: subnet sandbox join failed for "10.0.0.0/24": error creating vxlan interface: file exists"
```

I have a suspicion the VPN I'm using is causing the issue but I can't take it out of production. Does anyone have any idea how to work around it?

I'm using a regular overlay network generated by the docker stack file. Any help would be greatly appreciated